# My website google index suddenly increase and also suddenly reduced

Tags: seo, sitemap, google-index

Yesterday before i sleep, i check my site index. i get about 50 index on google.
today morning when i wake up, i get 250 index on google. and my page ranking better on several keyword.
than i add 1 page and 2 canonical link, add 404 page header, and resubmit sitemap.
and after 2 hour, its going down to 50 index again. and my page ranking just rolled back to previous day.

what is actually happen? is it because i resubmit sitemap?
until now, google still crawl my website. do they try to refresh the index?

Comment: Just out of interest how did you check the position of your key words?

Comment: i have list of my keyword target. and i always check it daily. and i also have tracker that will save referrer if its com from google. and i add it to my keyword target too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is constantly updating their index which will occasionally result in sites getting a temporary boost or drop in rankings. This sounds like what you experienced.

Some advice: whenever you see a sudden change in your Google rankings, either for better or for worse, don't make any significant changes to your website immediately after. By doing so you make it impossible to tell whether the change is permanent or not and, if things change again, it makes it more difficult to determine what caused it to occur. The only exception to this would be if you had made a change immediately before a big rankings drop. In that case a rollback is warranted.

Comment: They may have also connected to a different data center which had a different index.

Comment: again, google make fun of me. now my index increase to 69. webmaster sitemap said that 79 is already at web index.

Comment: now its increase again to 330. i just don't understand what is google trying to do. haha google is funny.